# Java 1.6: Public variable won't work

Tags: java, eclipse, string, macos, public

I'm very new to java (about 1 week), and i'm stuck on a bit of code. I've looked everywhere, but nothing works. I'm trying to send a string from a MainProgram class to a FileWriter class.

MainProgram:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MainProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        static answer;
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter something so I can write it to a file");
        String answer = Input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("You said ");
        System.out.print(answer);

    }
}
```

FileWriter:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class FileWriter{
    public static void SaveList() throws FileNotFoundException{
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("OMGIMAFILELOLZ.txt");
            writer.println(answer);
            writer.close();

    }
}
```

No matter what I do, I can't pass the answer string onto the FIleWriter class. Please help!
BTW Please don't make the answer too complex. I just came from QBASIC, and i'm only 12, so keep it simple please!

Comment: You need to declare a parameter to the `SaveList` method, and then call this method from `main` by passing `answer` as the argument.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Defacing a question by totally changing it's entire content (including title and tags) after receiving answers to the original question is inappropriate here. If you have a new question, post it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

1. In this line         `static answer;` you have not mentioned the
   [data type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) of answer.
2. main is already a static block,so you can not declare static
   variables inside main method
3. declare answer in the class level like this `public static String
   answer;`

class level syntax

```
public class MainProgram {
public static String answer;//class level declaration
public static void main(String args[])
{
//some codes
}
```

Comment: @R.S we can do any thing no one is prohibiting us but compiler will not compile.

Comment: @R.S I said in the 2nd point that you can not declare a static variable inside method because main is already static.

Answer (score 0):

```
static answer;
```

First of all data type is missing for that.

And you cannot declare fields in methods.

That should be

```
static String answer;
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
   //   answer = Input.nextLine();
```

Then in `FileWriter`  class,

```
 writer.println(MainProgram.answer);
```